# Spring Rest Template + MapStruct 400 BAD_REQUEST error

Tags: java, spring, rest, mapstruct

Having the following implementation:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("key", "72hdjas721398721");

    Application application = appRepository.findById(customerId)
            .get();
    BasicRequestMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(BasicRequestMapper.class);
    BasicRequest basicRequest = mapper.customerToBasicRequest(application);

    HttpEntity<BasicRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<>(basicRequest, headers);      
    try {
        ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
                Response.class);
        return response;
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
```

Short summary of the implementation: I'm using Springs RestTemplate in order to do a POST request sending a POJO on it.

While executing the exchange, I get the following error:

```
2019-03-14 11:19:51.300 DEBUG 7448 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
{"key":"unknown.error.found","message":"Unexpected end-of-input in field name\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@42450be5; line: 1, column: 1523]"}
```

This message is already handled by the server side, hence I get the ""key":"unknown.error.found","message" in the error message. But the second part seems to be an error throw by Jackson while de-serializing the message.

The object that I'm sending is a simple POJO with few properties with getters  and setters. I'm using mapstruct in order to map only the properties that I want from the entities to this pojo.

Sample: `2019-03-14 11:19:50.763 DEBUG 7448 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [BasicRequest [bankAccount=BankAccountDto [iban=DE12500105170648489890, holder=1]] as "application/json"`

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the debug output

```
2019-03-14 11:19:50.763 DEBUG 7448 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [BasicRequest [bankAccount=BankAccountDto [iban=DE12500105170648489890, holder=1]] as "application/json"
```

It seems that the `RestTemplate` is not sending our JSON content. Not sure how your depenencies look like. However, most probably you are missing jackson as a dependency. If you add it then it should send the proper data.

Comment: I have jackson as dependency (transitive dependency as part of spring boot) and it is used automatically for message conversion. It is triggered automatically because of the content type - in this case json.